# Method signature to take the same array in array extension

Tags: swift

I want to write a generic method in an Array extension which takes a parameter type that is also an array where the element types are the same (for the caller of the array extension and the parameter). This is kind of what I mean (but none of them works):

```
extension Array {
    func doSomethingWithAnotherArray(arr: Self) {

    }
}

extension Array {
    func doSomethingWithAnotherArray<T: Array<Element>>(arr: T){

    }
}

extension Array {
    func doSomethingWithAnotherArray<T: Array<U>, U>(arr: T) where U == Element{

    }
}
```

So I can use it as:

```
let x = [1, 2]
let y = [3, 4]
x.doSomethingWithAnotherArray(arr: y)
Since x and y has the same elements.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simply pass parameter of type `Array`

```
extension Array {
    func doSomethingWithAnotherArray(arr: Array) {
        ... // do something  
    }
}
```

---

```
[Int].doSomethingWithAnotherArray(arr: [Int]) // works
[Int].doSomethingWithAnotherArray(arr: [String]) // doesn't work
```

Comment: Out of genuine interest: is it specified somewhere that this is intended to be the syntax for referring to the same specialization of a generic type, or is this just something that you tried and happens to work?

Comment: @Arkku honestly, I said to myself, when I extended `Array` and then I used the same type in parameter of method, it should be array with elements of same type. Then I tried it in playground and it worked.

Comment: Ok. I tried it myself, but it seems more like a bug than the intended syntax, since it would seem to make it really obscure to allow mismatching types of the same generic class/struct as arguments in extensions.

Comment: @Arkku try to declare parameter of type `Element`, then try to call this method on some array. Xcode will suggest you to pass element of the same type as elements inside array are. This doesn't look like a bug. But I have to say that I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't follow that example. If the type of argument is `Element`, then I'm explicitly saying that I want an argument with the same `Element` type as the receiver. By that logic the corresponding syntax for "`Array` with the same `Element`" would be `Array<Element>` (as per my answer), whereas plain `Array` should be "any `Array`". For example, let's consider the (admittedly useless) `func containsMoreThan(_ other: Array) -> Bool { return count > other.count }`. This doesn't require the same element type, so why would it be constrained to it? And how to define it without the constraint?

Comment: @Arkku `Array` is exactly the same as `[Element]` and `Array<Element>`

Comment: @LeoDabus Ok, what if I have a custom generic struct `Foo` that I extend in the same way, does `func (_ foo: Foo)` also require the argument to have the same specialization as the receiver? (Note that I'm not saying that I don't believe you or Robert, I do, I just find it odd and would like a link to the specification where this comes from.)

Comment: Ok, upon further reflection it makes sense: you can't have a non-specialized argument of a generic type without making the function also generic in itself, and this function isn't. You are correct.

Answer (score 1):

If the only restriction is that `Element` of the argument is the same as that of the receiver:

```
extension Array {
    func doSomethingWithAnotherArray(arr: Array<Element>) {
        // …
    }
}
```

edit: As seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53925652/204883), a simple `Array` suffices, since this function is not generic in itself, and in context of the generic type, `Array` is already specialized to the type of the receiver.

If you need to place other restrictions on `Element`, use `extension Array where Element …`.